# can't run the dotcloud CLI after installing it using pip on Mac

Tags: command-line-interface, dotcloud

I ran the following commands:

```
sudo pip install dotcloud
```

Which reported back to me that it installed correcly, but when I tried to run `dotcloud setup`, it didn't find the command

So I tried to uninstall it

sudo pip uninstall dotcloud

and reinstall using the command above

but still, terminal doesn't find the cli

do I need to change my $PATH variable?
It currently looks like this:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

I've heard that pip install should put the command in /usr/local/bin but when I do ls in there, it isn't in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're global python installation is broken in some way. Most likely, there's a problem with where pip is installing your packages.  You can try to diagnose this problem using `pip freeze` to tell you what's installed and `which python` to see where your default python is located.

---

I'd highly recommend using virtualenv/virtualenvwapper instead of the global environment for projects.  These tools allow you to manage dependencies of projects much easier than trying to manage them from within your global python installation.

Since you already have pip, you can pip install the tools to your global environment (only need to do this once):

`sudo pip install virtualenv`

`sudo pip install virtualenwrapper`

Now you make make a virtual environments for each project that you workon.  To make you're first project do:

`mkvirtualenv myproject`

Virtualenvwrapper should "load" that environment for you.

`(myproject) $`

Now, install your packages with pip:

`pip install dotcloud`

Check to see the list of packages:

`pip freeze`

References:

- http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#using-get-pip
- http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/
- http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: pip freeze tells me dotcloud version 0.9.5 is installed

Comment: ok, so it's installed, but now you need to find where it's installed. If you open the python interpreter and try `import dotcloud` do you get an error?

Comment: Looks like my mac doesn't like commands installed from pip. pip freeze tells me that the following things are installed: `irtualenv==1.10
virtualenv-clone==0.2.4
virtualenvwrapper==4.1.1` but even after restarting the terminal, it still reports it can't find the mkvirtualenv command

Comment: It looks like you'll have to find the installations of python on your Mac.  It's going to vary by version.  There's a resource that shows an example that may or may not be applicable, but should give you an idea of what you need to do to find the version of python where all your pip packages are being installed: http://sevas.github.io/2011/06/14/multiple-python-osx.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help you're giving me. I'm curently looking a the post you mentioned. Also, which python outputs `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: I got it to work! I noticed that when I ran pip uninstall dotcloud, it listed all the files which would be deleted. Most of them were in the site-packages/dotcloud directory, but a fille called `dotcloud` was located in `/usr/local/share/python`. Adding this path to the $PATH variable did the trick

Comment: Nice, Glad to hear that your up and running!